# C++ implicit return type in recursive function, how does this work

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search, undefined-behavior

I don't understand how this is supposed to work..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
int binarySearch(const vector<T>& vect, const T& k, int i, int j) {
    int m;
    if(i > j) {
        return -1;
    }
    m = (i+j) / 2;
    if(vect[m] == k) {
        return m;
    } else {
        if(k < vect[m]) {
            binarySearch(vect, k, i, m-1); // No return statement
        } else {
            binarySearch(vect, k, m+1, j); // No return statement
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    vector<int> vect = {10, 15, 21, 30, 40, 60, 100};
    int pos = binarySearch(vect, 60, 0, vect.size()-1);
    cout << pos << endl; // prints 5

    return 0;
}
```

Why does this binary search function work even if return is omitted in function call? Only thing that comes in my mind is that, when return m is called, the return sent back across the stack because the functions in the middle are not returning anything.

At the first I though it was some kind of VS optimization/refactoring (VS2015  apparently allows `void main()` so I thought it could be), but this happens even in Eclipse. This are the compiler options

```
g++ -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11
```

I just found it out for case, I'd never think that something like this would have worked in cases where recursion happens.

I read in other answers of questions that missing return statement is called undefined behavior in ISO C++, but is there something up for recursive functions or this is just another case of undefined behavior?

Comment: Missing `return` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: If you have your compilers warning levels set to something sensible, your compiler should indicate the problem.

Comment: works for you is just one of the worse possible results of undefined behaviour

Comment: "Why does this binary search function work " - it *doesn't*. After lying to the compiler that you would return `int` from your function, you invoked *undefined behavior*. That is *appeared* to work isn't relevant, because that observation has no concrete definition to back it up. Don't confuse *observed* behavior with *defined* behavior. The latter leads to the former; not the other way around. Take stock in Bryan's comment. It may seem subtle but it is *very* important.

Comment: Where did this code come from? Did you write this or find it somewhere?

Comment: @BryanChen I know and that's why I asked.... my friend and me are implementing data structures in C++. He needs help by me usually and he came up with this snippet. I said "No this is wrong" but he said "how? it's working for me", so I tried and I got perplexed. Better to hear it's undefined behavior than another nasty side of C++ (well it still is tho)

Comment: Guys, even though it's UB, I think the implicit question is: why doesn't MSVC or gcc generate an error about this when it's clearly illegal?

Comment: Oh, I made my search and didn't find a question with recursive function... but yeah pretty that is similar. A user explains in comments even why something like this may (or may not happen). Flag as duplicate then, sorry

Comment: Also similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459810/how-do-c-progs-get-their-return-value-when-a-return-is-not-specified-in-the-f and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36566312/why-does-this-recursive-function-work @BlackBox do you have a favorite dupe target? I did not find an exact target to close against yet; any of the above close enough in your eyes?

Comment: Nvm, I found a good one.

Comment: This one was for *my* case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887837/c-recursive-return-function-without-return

Comment: @BlackBox Thanks; but I could not use that because it has no answers. Closed that as a dupe of the other one too.

Comment: Oh that one you chose is good and much better too